# Calculating Distance and Bearing North Azimuth (0 degrees pointing North) in ArcGIS Near tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, proximity, bearing

I am trying to calculate distance and bearing in ArcMap using the tool Near, and although it works I need the results to be calculated using North Azimuth (0 degrees pointing North) and not Polar which is the default. I can change these settings for when I am editing but not for toolbox tools.

How do I calculate distance and bearing in ArcMap using the tool Near and  North Azimuth (0 degrees pointing North)?

---

To be honest I think I need to understand the results the tool is giving me before running any code. According to the Near tool help, when the GEODESIC method is used, the angle is within the range of -180° to 180°, with 0° to the north, 90° to the east, 180° (or -180°) to the south, and -90° to the west. However this is what I am getting which doesn't match that. I calculate the bearing from the blue points to the green square. Values are in decimal degrees.

[image: Near tool results in decimal degrees]

So even if I run the python code I don't think I will get the correct results.

Am I missing something?

Comment: See "Example 3" from Near tool help (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm). Is this what you want?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.